Audio Won't Stop Playing When Using MediaPlayer In Andriod Studio
I've developed a simple Android application where you can play and stop audio using MediaPlayer. However the audio doesn't stop when requested to.
Here is a breakdown of the app. There are two buttons in a column. The first button prepares and plays an audio file. The second stops playing the audio file.
Here is the code for the MainActivity
// Sound Effect Uri
val soundEffectUri = "android.resource://com.example.audiotest/raw/sound_effect"

// App Layout
Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {

        // Button That Plays Audio
    Button(onClick = { AudioClass(this).play() })
        { Text(text = "Start") }

        // Button That Stops Audio
        Button(onClick = { AudioClass(this).stop() })
        { Text(text = "Stop") }

The logic for the MediaPlayer is kept in a seperate class. Here it is
// Class That Holds MediaPlay Logic
class AudioClass(context: Context) {

    // Instance Of MediaPlayer
    val mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer()

    // MediaPlayer Attributes
    init {
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(context, Uri.parse(soundEffectUri))
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM)
        mediaPlayer.isLooping = true
    }
 
    // Function That Prepares And Starts Audio
    fun play() {
        mediaPlayer.prepare()
        mediaPlayer.start()
    }

    // Function That Stops Audio
    fun stop() {
        mediaPlayer.stop()
    }

}

The problem of audio not stopping only occurs when the MediaPlayer is initialized outside of an Activity or Composable. I'd like to initialize it globally so that I can use it where ever it's needed.
Here is what the log cat says whenever I press the button that stops the audio.
2024-09-23 19:10:55.088 22661-22661 MediaPlayerNative com.example.audiotest E stop called in state 2, mPlayer(0xd25cb1e0)

2024-09-23 19:10:55.088 22661-22661 MediaPlayerNative com.example.audiotest E error (-38, 0)

2024-09-23 19:10:55.149 22661-22661 MediaPlayer com.example.audiotest E Error (-38,0)

Thanks for taking your time to read this question.

state 2 is the initialized state (see codes) - which suggests that you are recreating your AudioClass on each button click (e.g. AudioClass(this).stop() )- verify your button handlers are not creating a new instance.  See state diagram.  It works on prepare/play because it is valid to transition from initialized to prepared (even though it may be a new instance).

Do I need to reset ot release the MediaPlayer after or before stopping it?

The states of MediaPlayer are:
1 Idle
2 Initialized
3 Preparing
4 Prepared
5 Started
6 Paused
7 Stopped
8 PlaybackCompleted
9 End
10 Error
The Stop operation can't be called when the state is 2(Initialized).
It can only be called when the MediaPlayer is in the Started, Paused, or PlaybackCompleted states
Check it based on the above logic.

So how do I fix this problem, by getting rid of the init{} keywork? When I tried that it produced an error.

Looks like you are staring and stopping 2 different players.
You should create and remember only one instance.
